# How to apply css for 1900x600 width screen resolution only

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Am working on page layout which doesn't work properly in 1600x900 screen resolution.

My code:

```
@media screen and (width: 1600px) {

#form_div {

  margin-left:920px;
}

}
```

My code is not working.Any suggestions please.

Comment: "My code is not working" doesn't really provide us with any information about what your problem is.  Please try to be more specific and also include your html and desired result

Comment: You probably do not want to target just the 1900px width. Try using "min-width" instead of "width". Also note that if you are looking to match the screen size (not the window size) you should use "min-device-width".

Comment: Actually i have a form over the banner in home page.My requirement is to place the form right most side of the banner, but i the 1900x600 resolution the form displays in the center of the banner, ie my problem

Comment: Then you can use "float:right" for the form so that it will be in right side always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want settings specifically for 1900px use:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1900px) and (min-width: 1900px) {
  #form_div {
    margin-left:920px;
  }
}
```

But, if I were you, I would use:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1850px) {
  #form_div {
    margin-left:920px;
  }
}
```

Just for not being too restrictive and considering there could be a scrollbar.

Comment: What does not work exactly @VeNaToR ? I modified my suggested code so that the min width is a bit smaller (maybe with the window borders or scrollbar you don't make it to 1900px)

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (min-width:1899px){
  #your div {margin-left:920px;}   }
```

The above code says that the minimum resolution when this code will work is 1899px and than it will give you perfect 1900px display style as you want.

Comment: i should work try once more ! i have edited it a bit to make it work . I would suggest adding this code at the top of your stylesheet .

Comment: I posted my comment in the wrong answer. Sorry! Corrected!